# What does the constraint Required do?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

What does the constraint Required do in the form builder? If a field was not submitted (not empty value!), I don't receive a corresponding error message. This field is just ignored.

```
$builder 
    ->add('firstname', TextType::class, [ 'constraints' => [new NotBlank()], 'required'=>true]) 
    ->add('lastname', TextType::class, [ 'constraints' => [new NotBlank(),] ,'required'=>true])
```

How can say, that the field always MUST be submitted?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Required mean your field need a value tu be be submitted. It's similar to the HTML behaviour.

**EDIT:**

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#constraints

https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/without_class.html#form-option-constraints

The issue is on your constraints, I don't know for sure but if adding those to your form don't fix your problem, have a look att adding assert to your Entity attached to your form

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/NotBlank.html

Then validate this entity in your controller

https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html

And relying on this you might add errors to the form.

Comment: The submitted data come from an another application over REST-API. If the required filed is not present in the submitted data, an error should be generated. How can I do it?

Comment: I have these fields
$builder
            ->add('firstname', TextType::class, [
                'constraints' => [new NotBlank()]
            ])
            ->add('lastname', TextType::class, [
                'constraints' => [new NotBlank(),]
            ])

If the field firstname was not submitted, an error must be occurred. 
Should I check self, if the field is present in the request?

Comment: no, the solution with the form builder is the best solution for my case

Comment: yes `$form->isValid()` should return false, if the field firstname absent.
`'required'=>true` takes no effect. It's just for the HTML5 attribute "required"
I'v added some code to my question.

Comment: You're right, I edited some options that make sense to me else I don't really know. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

A colleague has found the solution:

In the related entity, you need to define a callback-function like this:

```
/**
 * Check bank account by "CUSTOMER" - not null
 * Because NotNull() not working in form type!
 * @Assert\Callback()
 */
public function validateBankaccount(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
{
    if ($this->type == self::TYPE_CUSTOMER && is_null($this->bankAccount)) {
        $context->buildViolation('Bank account is required!')
            ->atPath('bankAccount')
            ->addViolation();
    }
}
```